# Publish web application into azure web app using visual studio online

Tags: asp.net, azure, msbuild, azure-devops

I have created following Virtual Applications and Directories in the azure portal [Click here to view the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HC6hM.jpg)

And using visual studio online I can build and deploy the site into root folder but I couldn't figure it out how to deploy into a virtual directory I have created earlier.

[Click here to view the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CASx.jpg)

Any one have experience on this ? Appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: Not sure why there is a -1 on this, maybe it is the links to images.

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/q/33363271/25372

Answer (score 1):

The Azure Web App Deployment task can't deploy a virtual application as it uses Publish-AzureWebSiteProject which can't handle virtual applications.

You can check the poweshell script which uses WebDeploy to deploy a virtual application at website:https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-agent-tasks/issues/624