# How to use Azure PowerShell script to publish package to web app virtual application in VSO

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I see the new Build definitions of Visual Studio Online have not supported 'Azure WebApp Deployment build step' to deploy Virtual Application (Sub site).
So I try on using 'Azure PowerShell build step' but couldn't find out the script. 
I also tried this tutorial: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn642480.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396
But stuck in step generate folder called PublishScripts. Because I've already created Azure WebApp and VSO Project, not starting at a blank.

**Updated:**
I've solved by creating & upload a custom tfx build task based on ps msdeploy.exe

Comment: The tutorial link is broken.

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/q/33208353/25372

Comment: Hi JTew, I've sold by creating & upload new tfs build task (based on ps msdeploy.exe), Thanks for care.

Comment: I've sold  = I've solved, could you post your solution as an answer?

Comment: oh, my mistake. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've solved by creating & uploading a custom tfx build task based on ps msdeploy.exe

Comment: YOu did not need to create a custom tfx package. All you needed to use was the "run some powershell" task...

Answer (score 0):

You should use the build in Azure Web Application deployment step.

[image]
This is by far the easyest method.

Comment: Hi, Azure Web App Deployment doesn't support option to deploy to a virtual application of a Web App.

Comment: There isn't a way that I can see to use Azure Web App Deployment for Virtual Directories/Applications under an Azure Web App.